# rank of the matrix dependent on parameter

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I want to find rank of the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
     0  &  p  &  6 &  -p & p+2\\
    3-p & p-2 & p-1 & -1 & 1\\
    -4  &  2  &  0  &  2 & p-3
\end{pmatrix}$$
I changed 1st with 3rd row, and then I tried doing some changes between rows but nothing got me anywhere... Could anyone help with 2/3 first steps? I have test from this today :/

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: HINT: Rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent rows/columns of a matrix

Comment: @DeBARtha can I add/substract columns as I can with rows??

Comment: Yes you can, row rank = column rank.

Comment: Potentially the rank is different depending on what value is assigned to $p$.  Just looking at entries that don't depend on $p$ one can ascertain that the rank is at least two, and of course the rank is at most three.  Did you perhaps omit part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is always less than or equal the minimum of the number of rows and of columns. In this case, $\;3\;$ , so $\;rk(A)\le3\;$ . Take now the first three *columns* and form a square matrix with them and evaluate its determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&p&6\\
3-p&p-2&p-1\\
-4&2&0\end{vmatrix}=-4p(p-1)+12(3-p)+24(p-2)=-4p^2+16p-12\stackrel?=0\iff$$

$$p^2-4p+3=0\iff(p-3)(p-1)=0$$

and thus for $\;p\neq1,3\;$ the matrix has rank three. Now you can check what happens with the two particular cases $\;p=1,3\;$ by substituting and, say. reducing (by rows or by columns: it will give the same result for the rank, of course).